# How to speed up Magento 1.9 Website?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new in Magento & I am facing this problem. I have cleared log files, cache , etc. But then also site is very slow. I have near about 150 products (simple). Please guide me on this. The site is not live, I am working on localhost.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your problem? And with no code or more detailed information we can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many points which you should take care of, when optimizing magento's shop performance.

- Enable Gzip compression
- Enable Flat Catalog
- Enable Magento Cache
- Optimize images
- Merge CSS and Javascript Files
- Clean Up Magento Database & Logs
- Try to remove/disable modules which are of no use, or try to merge small modules because if number of modules are higher then your website's performance will be slower.
- Use any PHP Accelerators like APC, Xcache, eAccelerator etc.

Apart from that, check gtmetrix.com or google page speed tools recommendations for more.